# What do you mean by you can create many sort sequences using Comparator in java?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, comparable

In comparable ,Only one sort sequence can be created while in comparator many sort sequences can be   created . what is sort sequence exactly means here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, a sort sequence is just an order relation (mathematically). It is a way of ranking objects.

What it means is that when an Object implements the `Comparable` interface, only one order can be defined. Let's take a more concrete example with the custom class `MyFile`:

```
public class MyFile implements Comparable<MyFile> {
    private String name;
    private Date creationDate;
    private String author;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyFile other) {
        return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
}
```

In this example, the class MyFile implements the `Comparable` interface, which sorts a collection of `MyFile` by ascending name. It implements one sort sequence. But if you want to sort them by descending name ? Or by date ? Or by author ? Then you have to create different orderings. However, you cannot implement a second time the `Comparable` interface. This is when you create custom `Comparator` to have the behaviour you expect. Each `Comparator` implements a sort sequence.

```
public class DateComparator implements Comparator<MyFile> {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyFile f1, MyFile f2) {
        return f1.getDate().compareTo(f2.getDate());
    }
}

public class ReverseNameComparator implements Comparator<MyFile> {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyFile f1, MyFile f2) {
        return f2.getName().compareTo(f1.getName());
    }
}
```

Those are two other sort sequence defined for the same class.

Answer (score 1):

By having your class implement `Comparable`, you are giving it a natural ordering. E.g., `Integer`s are sorted by their `int` value. However, you could implement additional custom `Comparator`s to achieve any ordering you wish. For example, if we stick to the `Integer` example, you could implement a `Comparator` to sort `Integer`s by the sum of their digits, and by whether or not they are divisible by 7, or by any order you could think of.